# Работа сокетов, accept, recv, send. Возможна ли работа в одном потоке?

Tags: c++, сокет

Хочу сделать так, чтобы приложение совмещало функционал сервера и клиента:
создаю сокет для listen(), жду клиентов, с помощью accept() создаю каждому клиенту отдельный сокет, в него хочу отправлять данные и получать из него.

Проблемы:
acсept() блокирует свой thread, пришлось вынести в отдельный, хотелось бы оставить в основном thread. Возможно ли это сделать не теряя "заявки" от будущих участников?
recv() блокирует thread, будут ли потери данных, если я не буду делать recv() некоторое время? Т.е. буду чередовать recv() и send() периодически, не создавая для них отдельные thread?
Нужно ли для каждого сокета создавать отдельный экземпляр структуры SOCKADDR_IN или можно менять содержимое и продолжать ссылаться на него при работе с новосозданными сокетами?

/*Планируется, что при первом подключении нового клиента ему будет отослан список активных клиентов, он примет, сравнит со своим, сам добавит тех, которых у него нет. Не уверен, но кажется, что это называют P2P. В приложении происходят некоторые изменения, как только они происходят, нужно каждому активному клиенту сообщить об этом. И так будет делать каждый участник, каждый отправляет о себе каждому другому. Нужно асинхронно отправлять и принимать данные*/

Какую литературу посоветуете на эту тему? На русском, либо на английском с картинками.

Comment: да, это возможно - используйте мультиплексирование. А именно, смотрите в сторону select (старый, добрый, работает везде, скорее всего Вам будет достаточно) до poll/epoll/kpoll/IOCP

Comment: Вместо этого следует использовать неблокирующий или асинхронный режим работы для сокетов.